# $M=A\cup B$, $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous in $A\cap B$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

In order to prove:

$M=A\cup B$, $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous in $A\cap B$

does it suffice to prove:
for $a\in A\cap B$:

since $f|_A$ is continuous, then $\forall \epsilon>0$ exists $\delta_1>0$ such that

$$d(x,a)<\delta_1\implies d(f(x),f(a))<\epsilon$$

same for $f|_B$:
$$d(y,a)<\delta_2\implies d(f(y),f(a))<\epsilon$$

Taking $\delta_3 = max\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ will work, right? Then:

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta_3>0| d(f(y),f(a))<\epsilon$$

thus $f$ is continuous.

Now, what would be a good example of $f:M\to N$ (where $M=A\cup B)$ such that the restriction $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are continuous but not $f$?

Comment: $(A \cup B) \subset A$, and $f$ is continuous on $A$, so it should be continuous on $(A \cup B)$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I imagine you'll need to assume that $A$ and $B$ are open.

Comment: @Neil, that's not correct...

Comment: Neil's comment seems correct to me? How can it not be continuous on a subset?

Comment: Gah! I meant to write $A \cap B$, although that still may very well not be true.

Comment: I meant what Neil meant to write, of course :-);.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the final example, consider $M=[0,2), N=\mathbb{R},  A=[0,1), B=[1,2)$. Then, take $f(x)=x$ when $x \in A$, and $f(x)=x+1$ when $x \in B$. Obviously $f$ is continuous when restricted only to $A$ or $B$, but there's a discontinuity at $x=1$ when examining it over all of $M$.